# Python 3.9.7 xlsxwriter not creating excel file. Workbook.Close error

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

```
# import xlsxwriter module
import xlsxwriter

# Workbook() takes one, non-optional, argument
# which is the filename that we want to create.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('sample.xlsx')

# The workbook object is then used to add new
# worksheet via the add_worksheet() method.
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Use the worksheet object to write
# data via the write() method.
worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello..')
worksheet.write('B1', 'Geeks')
worksheet.write('C1', 'For')
worksheet.write('D1', 'Geeks')
print(1)
# Finally, close the Excel file
# via the close() method.
workbook.close() #someerror here
print(2)
```

**this code doesn't not create excel file**
**Please check attached images**
*Please Help*

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYsu3.png)

[Run Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GcLc.png)

[pip list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLc0G.png)

Comment: Please add the error you get to your question.

Comment: DO NOT ADD IMAGES of our code. Post is here instead so people can reproduce it.

Comment: No error is displayed....program exits without showing any error
Robin- i have added the code